# Python file showing source code in browser instead of running?

Tags: python, fastcgi

```
#!/home3/tonyss/public_html/python

print "Hello, World"
```

Display showing source code **print "Hello, World"**.

I'm using fastCGI on bluehost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Python issue. You must configure the web server to run the Python program and relay its output to the client. At present it is simply treating the Python file as textual content, not running it.